# Why cant we install matplotlib in windows in python 3.10?

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

Guys I cant install matplotlib in windows10 in vscode terminal. Pics of errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcPiw.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing its a version error with your numpy installation. If your python is version 3.x try using `pip3` instead.